# Set Focus on iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, focus

I am trying to set focus on an iFrame with jQuery. Using the console, I am able to grab an element within the iFrame, so the issue is not cross-domain related. Here is the code I am using:

```
document.getElementById('iFrameId').focus();
console.log($(focusElement).is(":focus")); //returns false
```

Comment: Why do you need to set focus on the iframe? Dont you want to set focus on specific element inside iframe?

Comment: I need to set focus on the iFrame for accessibility... Is it best to not set focus on the iFrame, but rather the first relevant element within the iFrame?

Comment: Depending what you are expecting. But if you want to make an iframe focusable, you should use tabindex attribute.